# Creating deck of cards with suit and value C++

Tags: c++, string

Basically, i have to generate a deck of cards that displays both the suit and value like "Seven of Hearts". I have to use constant array of strings and I also have to somehow encode both the rank and suit of a card into a single integer value. So I tried to put the suit and value in separate strings and then put them together in another string, but it doesn't seem to be working. I get red lines under the "<<".

```
const int numSuit = 4;
const int numCard = 8;

string suits[numSuit] = { "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs" };
string cards[numCard] = { "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" };

for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < 7; j++ )
    {
        for ( int k = 0; k < 32; k++ )
        {
            deck[i] = << cards[j] << " of "  << suits[i];
```

I don't understand what's wrong with this.

Comment: Your loop sizes are wrong. Don't use constants, use the length of the suites and cards lists respectively.

Comment: You might want to read the section in your fine book on the stream insertion operator, `<<`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you've only got 28 cards here.

Second of all, why are you nesting an additional layer deep?

```
string deck[28];

const int numSuit = 4;
const int numCard = 8;

string suits[numSuit] = { "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs" };
string cards[numCard] = { "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" };
int index = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < 7; j++ )
    {
            deck[index++] = cards[j] + " of " + suits[i];
    }
}
```

if you ran it this way, you'd be able to have all 28 combinations stored.

I hope I understood what you were asking.

You definitely didn't need that extra loop.

Comment: I still get the error: "Expected an expression" for the red squiggly line under the "<<" after "deck[index++]" though. how do i fix that?

Comment: You might need to make sure the deck array is of type string.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
deck[i] = cards[j] + " of " + suits[i]
```

The `<<` operator works for streams, not strings. We concatenate strings with `+`.

**Edit**: More about `<<`. `<<` is an operator, (Like `+`, `-`, `*`, etc.) and like all operators, it requires both an l-value (something to left of it), and an r-value (something to the right of it). So `a = << b` will not work, because you're missing an l-value for the operator.

Comment: I changed it to what you said and I get the error: no operator "+" matches these operands. operand types are std::string + const char[5].

Comment: That's odd, it works for me. `std::string a = "hello,"; std::string b = "world!"; std::string c = a + " " + b; std::cout << c << "\n";` prints "hello, world!"